# String sent inside an intent is not matching?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

Consider the scenario: I made two android Apps, say A & B. B Scans an NFC tag, stored a string "nfcservice" and I stored that string in a byte array, say TEMP_MSG as hex. After that I converted that array into String and sent it to App-A. In App-A I tried to match it, but it fails everytime. What is the problem? Can you suggest something?

App-B code:

```
//nfcservice
byte[] TEMP_MSG = {(byte)0x6E, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x65,
                   (byte)0x72, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x65}; 

String nfcservicestring = new String(TEMP_MSG);
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.apps.metromanager.MetroManagerActivity");
intent.putExtra("keyword", nfcservicestring);
startActivity(intent);
```

App-A code:

```
public class MetroManagerActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView myText;
    String myString;    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_metro_manager);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            myString = bundle.getString("keyword");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(myString.equals("nfcservice")) {
                LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);
                myText = new TextView(this);
                myText.setText("Welcome");
                lView.addView(myText);
                setContentView(lView);
            } else {
                LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);
                myText = new TextView(this);
                myText.setText("Bye Bye");
                lView.addView(myText);
                setContentView(lView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the string in the intent of App A and B to see what actually differs?

Comment: nfcservice is the name of the String not the value of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your byte initialization has a fault, at the 5th byte you have:

```
 , byte)0x65,
```

Instead of:

```
  ,(byte)0x65,
```

However, why don't you try to get some other attributes from your bundle object, and examine them by debugging and watching?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it was a bug in your typing, but the byte array expression is wrong:

```
byte[] TEMP_MSG = { (byte)0x,(byte)0x6E, ...};
```

There is a bug in the first expression (byte)0x,

Appart from that, if you can't get the string inside the bundle, you will have a NPE in the code:

```
if(myString.equals("nfcservice"))
{
...
}
```

It's better to check equality like this:

```
if ("nfcservice".equals(myString)) {

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate why checking equality like you suggested is better

Comment: If myString is null, myString.equals("nfcservice") throws a NullPointerException, cause myString is null. But if you call equals method on a string object "nfcservice" ("nfcservice", a string that exists) you wont have a NPE, simply the comparison returns false because nfcservice != null.